# Does Android's DUND support DUN DT (aka Dial Up client aka Data Terminal aka "dund --connect")

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm going to build an application that allows an Android to connect to other phone's DUN (dial-up) bluetooth service, to use this other phone as an internet modem.

It seems like dund is included into Android (i'm targetting at 2.1 -- not sure if it is actually included there?), so I wonder if it supports "dund --connect" command not just --listen?

Or, maybe, there're other ways to implement that? Existing software maybe?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you can visit this
http://www.bluesoleil.com/products/SoftwareDetail.aspx?ProductID=S0001201009150001

Comment: Thanks, already spoken to those guys, they dont seem to be available on retail...